# Make all column widths equal to the length of the widest column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to use the `max-content` option of `grid-template-columns` in such a way that **all** my columns have the width of the widest cell in the grid. The number of columns needs to stay dynamic.

Right now I have the CSS and HTML below. You can see that only the width of the first column depends on the widest cell in my grid (cell 1). So in the desired result all columns should have the width of cell 1. Could someone tell me how to obtain a grid with a dynamic number of columns and a column width that depends on the biggest cell in my grid?

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 100px));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1 I am a very very wide cell</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **You can't.** This is not possible with CSS-Grid. You'll need javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Jquery solution

1. get the maximum width of all items:

```
var maxWWidth =Math.max.apply(Math, $('.item').map(function(){ return $(this).width(); }).get());
```

2. set it for all items

```
$('.item').width(maxWWidth);
```

**check snippet:**

```js
$(function(){
var maxWWidth =Math.max.apply(Math, $('.item').map(function(){ return $(this).width(); }).get());
$('.item').width(maxWWidth);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 100px));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1 I am a very very wide cell</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

> [image: Upvote if you like it]